# Two ExecuteScalar then query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to check if a customer ID exists in the Customer table, and if it exists in the table being queried.

If it doesn't exist in the Customer table or it already exists in the table being queried (or it is in Customer but also already exists in table in question) then I don't want it to insert the data.

I thought that maybe I could do if..if code  - more code - if..if code - else, but that didn't work. Here is what I mean:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer WHERE customer_id = @cid";
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();
    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();

    if (count < 1)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Customer ID does not exist and will not be submitted')</script>");
        tb0.Focus();
    }

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE customer_id = @cid";
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();
    int count2 = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
    if(count2 > 0)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Customer ID already exists in table_name and will not be submitted')</script>");
        tb0.Focus();
    }


    else
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(@cid, @val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)";
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close(); }
```

Unless I comment one out then the second one will work and the first I guess gets ignored? I'm not really sure but they both work if the other is commented out

Errors from answer:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

```
@"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customer_id = @cid) THEN BEGIN
    SELECT 'NO_CUSTOMER' as Result 
END ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE customer_id = @cid) THEN BEGIN
    SELECT 'ALREADY_RECORD' as Result
END ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(@cid, @val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5);
    SELECT 'SUCCESS' AS Result;
END";
```

Comment: what happens when both try to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try something a bit simpler, like this?

```
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText =
  @"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customer_id = @cid) THEN BEGIN
        SELECT 'NO_CUSTOMER' as Result 
    END ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE customer_id = @cid) THEN BEGIN
        SELECT 'ALREADY_RECORD' as Result
    END ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(@cid, @val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5);
        SELECT 'SUCCESS' AS Result;
    END";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@cid, ...);        
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@val1, ...);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@val2, ...);
...
switch((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar()) {
    case "NO_CUSTOMER":
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Customer ID does not exist and will not be submitted')</script>");
    tb0.Focus();
        break;
        case "ALREADY_RECORD":
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Customer ID already exists in table_name and will not be submitted')</script>");
    tb0.Focus();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL? I'm getting some errors that I'll add into the OP for you to see.. I updated the tag that this is sql server since it was a little vague. I am new to everything which is probably why I didn't think of this

Comment: This is for SQL Server.  You can run batches of commands in SQL Server like this.

Comment: I'll test it in SQL Server.. does the @ sign make it so you don't have to use concatenation with '+' on new lines?

Comment: Yeah.. all of the ELSE and THENs are underlined in SQL Server

Comment: And one more.. I removed the THEN and it worked, thanks

Comment: Using @"" in C# allows you to have multi-line strings, which is very useful for snippets of other languages.